# Allocating memory directly using cin and operator>>

Tags: c++, memory-management, cin

First time I see this syntax: `cin >> (ptr = new char);`

Is this a sure way to allocate memory dynamically? What are the possible pitfalls?

```
int main()
{
    char* charPtr;

    std::cout << "Enter a string: ";
    std::cin.getline((charPtr = new char), 5);//What's happening here?

    std::cout << charPtr << "\n";
    std::cout << "length: " << strlen(charPtr) << "\n";

    std::cin.clear();///Clearing eventually errors flags

    //Ignoring remained chars of the buffer.
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');

    delete [] charPtr;//freeing memory

    std::cout << "Enter a word: ";
    std::cin >> (charPtr = new char);//ALLOCATING MEMORY FOR 1 CHAR

    std::cout << charPtr << "\n";
    std::cout << "length: " << strlen(charPtr) << "\n";

    delete [] charPtr;//CRASH

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::cin.getline((charPtr = new char), 5);
```

This allocates room for only one character, which must be taken up by the null terminator. As such, if the user enters any characters at all on this line, it results in a buffer overflow, undefined behavior.

```
delete [] charPtr;
```

Undefined behavior, since you allocated with `new`, not `new[]`.

```
std::cin >> (charPtr = new char);
```

Guaranteed buffer overflow, unless the user terminates standard input (e.g. with ctrl-z on Windows), since this will have to read at least one character, and store at least 2 (the read character(s), plus the null terminator).

```
delete [] charPtr;
```

I think you can guess what this is by now.

Comment: +1 Lest we leave it out, `std::cout << charPtr << "\n";` is likewise undefined-behavior if the `std::getline` *fails* (its never checked), as the single char allocated is default-initialized, not value-initialized.